# ActiveRecord automatically overriding specifically selected fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following code:

```
L.select('"l"."id", "ps"."name", "ps"."proposed_start", "ps"."proposed_finished", COUNT(*) as total, SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ("l"."stop_at" - "l"."start_at"))) as duration, COUNT(CASE WHEN "l"."stop_at" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as ongoing').
  where(p_id: P.where.not(name: nil).select(:id)).
  eager_load(:p).
  group('"l"."id"')
```

> Note: `P.where.not(name: nil)` is just a random condition, in prod it
>   will be filtering out P's that don't belong to the user, but its not
>   *entirely* relevant to the question its there so I could confirm that ActiveRecord would run it as a sub-query.  I've also renamed the
>   models to L and P to obfuscate my project. Also I know the aggregate
>   function in my select are not SQL agnostic, I am using Postgresql.

However, when I run `.to_sql` to inspect what resulting SQL ActiveRecord will produce I discover to my dismay that I end up with:

```
SELECT "l"."id", 
       "p"."name", 
       "p"."proposed_start", 
       "p"."proposed_finished", 
       Count(*)                                                    AS total, 
       Sum(Extract(epoch FROM ( "l"."stop_at" - "l"."start_at" ))) AS duration, 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN "l"."stop_at" IS NULL THEN 1 
               ELSE NULL 
             END)                                                  AS ongoing, 
       "l"."id"                                                    AS t0_r0, 
       "l"."p_id"                                                  AS t0_r1, 
       "l"."user_id"                                               AS t0_r2, 
       "l"."start_at"                                              AS t0_r3, 
       "l"."stop_at"                                               AS t0_r4, 
       "l"."comment"                                               AS t0_r5, 
       "l"."created_at"                                            AS t0_r6, 
       "l"."updated_at"                                            AS t0_r7, 
       "l"."deleted_at"                                            AS t0_r8, 
       "l"."deleted_by_id"                                         AS t0_r9, 
       "p"."id"                                                    AS t1_r0, 
       "p"."name"                                                  AS t1_r1, 
       "p"."approved_by_id"                                        AS t1_r2, 
       "p"."user_id"                                               AS t1_r3, 
       "p"."proposed_start"                                        AS t1_r4, 
       "p"."proposed_finished"                                     AS t1_r5, 
       "p"."created_at"                                            AS t1_r6, 
       "p"."updated_at"                                            AS t1_r7, 
       "p"."p_status_id"                                           AS t1_r8, 
       "p"."approved_at"                                           AS t1_r9, 
       "p"."sub_unit_id"                                           AS t1_r10, 
       "p"."details"                                               AS t1_r11, 
       "p"."archived_at"                                           AS t1_r12, 
       "p"."archived_by_id"                                        AS t1_r13 
FROM   "l" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "p" 
                    ON "p"."id" = "l"."p_id" 
WHERE  "l"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
       AND "l"."p_id" IN (SELECT "p"."id" 
                          FROM   "p" 
                          WHERE  ( "p"."name" IS NOT NULL )) 
GROUP  BY "l"."id"
```

As you can see, ActiveRecord is automatically selecting all of the fields of the joined table "p" as well as my specific select. How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Why is it an issue when Rails selects more columns? Why do you use `eager_load` instead of `joins`?

Comment: Because they're not included in the aggregate function or the group by, the SQL will fail to execute.  Eager_load gives me LEFT OUTER JOIN whilst a joins will give me a INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with eager_load which appears to indiscriminately add all the fields of the associated model, ignoring your 'selects'. If you change it to joins for the INNER JOIN instead of the LEFT OUTER JOIN then it accepts your select and works as intended.